# Clarification of income tax rules for farm staking rewards (UK)

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

In the UK we have to pay Income Tax on crypto farm staking rewards.

I'm unsure as to at which point I'm legally obliged to pay income tax on staking rewards. Is it:

- As the rewards clock up on my DeFi staking platforms dashboard ?
- Only when I "Harvest" / "Claim" / "Withdraw" the rewards shown on the dashboard ?
- Or only when I convert the rewards into fiat (GBP) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant [manual](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/cryptoassets-manual/crypto21200) on tax on cryptoassets says (my highlighting):

> Some types of consensus require the ‘staking’ of exchange tokens which weights the entitlement to newly forged tokens, as is explained at CRYPTO10300.
> Whether such activity amounts to a taxable trade (with the tokens as trade receipts) depends on a range of factors such as:
>
> - degree of activity
> - organisation
> - risk
> - commerciality
>
> If the activity does not amount to a trade, the pound sterling value **(at the time of receipt)** of any tokens awarded will be taxable as income (miscellaneous income) with any appropriate expenses reducing the amount chargeable.